# React setState in callback function causes infinite loop in render()

Tags: reactjs, flux, es6-class

Using React 15.3.2 with ES6 and React Bootstrap.  I have a bad feeling my approach is wrong, but here's where I'm at.  I have a parent with several children that are form inputs:

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
    //... simplified for purpose of this post
    handleChange(field, value, errors) {
        this.setState({field: {value:errors}});  //causes infinite loop when rendering 
    }
    render() {
        <Bar value={this.state.inputVal1} handleChange={this.handleChange} />
        <Bar value={this.state.inputVal2} handleChange={this.handleChange} />
    }
}    

class Bar extends React.Component {
    //... simplified for purpose of this post
    handleChange(field, value, errors) {
        //pass to parent via callback
        this.props.handleChange(field, value, errors);
    }
    render() {
        <FormControl type='text' value={this.state.inputValue} onChange={this.handleChange} />
    }
}
```

I'm passing a callback to each of the children so when they change, they return the input data to the parent so that the parent can update it's state.  Doing this however causes an infinte loop when Foo is being rendered.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I assume you are using `this.state.field` in `Foo`? And you are passing `props.value` to `Bar`, but `Bar` is using `props.inputValue`? Anyway I'm assuming your `FormControl` is calling an `onChange` even if the value hasn't changed - why don't you check for value equality before calling it? Also please provide the code there.

Comment: yes, in Foo - this.state.field, props.value to Bar, but I had it wrong in Bar - this,state,inputValue, not props.inputValue.  Updated the sample code to reflect this.

I remove the setState call in Foo and can confirm onChange is called only when the value is changed - I enter some text.  The values are all being returned to Foo as I would expect, it's just the setState that causes things to break

Comment: I was thinking the same thing @DominicTobias was, that `FormControl` is calling its `onChange` prop immediately, causing `Bar` to invoke `handleChange` which causes `Foo` to re-render, causing an infinite loop. Please post your `FormControl` component code.

Comment: What is your state object suppose to look like.  The object you are passing into `setState()` looks wrong... not sure if your syntax is correct.  Did you mean something like this: `{ [fieldName]: { value, errors } }`.